# How to set Margin in TextElement?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

If I set the text of a TextBlock using TextElement in code behind then there is extra space is remaining below the text. How can I remove this space?

Xaml Code is below

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"
           IsTextSelectionEnabled="True"
           x:Name="TextMsg"
           FontSize="12">
 </TextBlock>
```

Code behind is below

```
 TextMsg.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = inlinerData.Text });
```

Attached is the screenshot of having extra space below the text
[image]

This is when I set text directly using Text-

[image]

Comment: What's the value of `inlinerData.Text` then? There is no extra space assuming this value doesn't contain any line breaks.

Comment: What's the extra space? can you share a screenshot to explain it?

Comment: value of inlinerData.Text is the message having single line text with no line breaks but still it adds around 10px extra margin down. It doesn't add text directly using Text= ""

Comment: I really didn't notice any difference.

Comment: I tried to use  TextElement  like this `new Run() { Text = "Test" }`. it has no extra space. can you check if  `inlinerData.Text` contains line break, or clean `inlinerData.Text` before using it.

Comment: Solved the issue by trimming line break in the end.

Comment: ok cool, please go ahead post your answer below.